# Logback property resource not found in jar

Tags: java, logback

I've built a jar with maven, which basically runs well.

However, there is a problem with the logback configuration.
The logback.xml configuration itself is loaded correctly and contains the following line:

```
<property resource="\conf\commonsCommandline.properties" />
```

However, logback shows the following error message when the jar is run:

```
-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [\conf\commonsCommandline.properties]
```

I've checked that the file exists in the folder conf inside the jar, which it does.

How can this problem be solved?

The same problem appears both when I package the jar with maven-shade-plugin and with maven-jar-plugin + maven-dependency-plugin.

(EDIT: Question updated with new information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the attribute `resource` is meant to point to a classpath resource, strip off the backslashes, and set it like this:

```
<property resource="conf/commonsCommandline.properties" />
```

Remember that Java resources within the classpath (i.e. within JARs files) must have the SLASH as separator.